# UIView & UIViewController App design

Tags: ios, ipad, uiview, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to get my head around view controllers, child view controllers, views, containers etc. I am making a simple app, that will have a set of icons down the left hand side, which when clicked will open a different screen on the right hand side. The basic design is:

[image]

The menu bar will always be on the left hand side, with the content being in the blue box. Am I correct in saying I should have the following structure:

[image]

Then when an image is pressed on the left UIView, I should push a new UIView to the right hand side? Or should these be UIViewControllers? Where do containers come into it?

Is it possible to do this through Storyboards, or is it not possible to link the buttons to push a new UIView to a different part of the screen and therefore I'll need to do it through code?

Comment: It seems like what you're trying to do here is basically the exact same as what a `UITabBar` does except you'd want the tabs on the left side instead of across the bottom.  Is this right?

Comment: Yes. Although I'm more trying to get my head around how the different elements should work together in good practice.

Comment: Well, the reason I asked is because you can always go look at how `UITabBar` handles the contents of each tab.  Each tab is its own `viewController`.  You can't actually use a `UITabBar` to accomplish this left hand menu, because `UITabBar` goes on the bottom (and I'm not aware of a way for changing this), but the concepts of how a `UITabBar` handles the different `viewControllers` should apply the same way to a custom layout such as this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to run with `UISplitViewController` which does most of this for you. But here is how I would go about it.

> 1. Have a HomeViewController that is the base layer of control. This class will handle:
>
>    1.1 The UI for the buttons on the left
>
>    1.2 Controlling what happens when a left button is pressed
>
>    1.3 Switching out child view controllers on the right
> 2. On the left side have a `UIView` call it navView or something and on the right have another `UIView` called containerView.
>
>    2.1 The navView will always be visible
>
>    2.2 The containerView is responsible for displaying your `childViewController`'s view
> 3. Whenever a button on the left is pressed you remove the current childViewController and add a new one.

[Here is a good tutorial on it](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/04/containing-viewcontrollers/)

---

Edit**

In response to comment:

*`When you initialize the TabBar it keeps an array of the viewControllers. So your right, viewDidLoad is only called once. All you have to do to achieve that is keep an array of all your viewControllers and switch them from there. I can post code on this if you want, it seemed a bit overkill for the initial question`*

Here a sample of how I do it:

```
- (void)updateChildViewController {

    //This is the VC that was being shown, but will be replaced by the new currentlyVisisbleViewController, we keep track of it so in the transitionFromViewController: method we have viewController to switch from.
    UIViewController *previousVisibleViewController = self.currentlyVisibleViewController;

    //We keep and array of both view controllers so that we only have to load them into memory once, so their viewDidLoad is only called once.
    if (!viewControllers) {
        viewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNull null], [NSNull null], nil];
    }

    //If a given VC has not been loaded before we know becuase it's spot in the viewControllers array will be Null. (as seen in the line above)
    if ([viewControllers objectAtIndex:self.displayType] == [NSNull null]) {

        id newlyLoadedViewController;

        //I have two display types I switch between, a map and list
        if (self.displayType == DTMap) {
            newlyLoadedViewController = [[MapViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MapViewController" bundle:nil];
        }
        else if (self.displayType == DTList) {
            newlyLoadedViewController = [[ListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ListViewController" bundle:nil];

        }

        //Set the object in it's location in viewControllers array
        [viewControllers setObject:newlyLoadedViewController atIndexedSubscript:self.displayType];
    }

    //Set the new currentlyVisibleViewController
    self.currentlyVisibleViewController = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:self.displayType];

    //Adjust the frame to fit in the contentView (or the "container" view)
    self.currentlyVisibleViewController.view.frame = self.contentView.frame;

    //Make sure that it resizes on rotation automatically along with the contentView.
    self.currentlyVisibleViewController.view.autoresizingMask = self.contentView.autoresizingMask;

    //Let the old VC know that is going to be removed if it exist. We lazy load the UIViewControllers so on intial launch, there is only one UIViewController loaded, once we switch to another one we will have a previousVisibleViewController.
    if (previousVisibleViewController) {
        [previousVisibleViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    }

    //Add the currentlyVisibleViewController as a childViewController
    [self addChildViewController:self.currentlyVisibleViewController];

    //If there was a previousVC then we animate between them
    if (previousVisibleViewController) {
        [self transitionFromViewController:previousVisibleViewController
                          toViewController:self.currentlyVisibleViewController
                                  duration:0.0f
                                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                                animations:^{}
                                completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                                    //Notify the new visible viewController than the move is done
                                    [self.currentlyVisibleViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

                                    //Tell the old one it is no longer on the screen and has been removed.
                                    [previousVisibleViewController removeFromParentViewController];
                                }];
    }

    //Otherwise it's the first time we are adding a child so we need to link the views
    else {

        //Add it to content view, calls willMoveToParentViewController for us. We only have to set this once.
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.currentlyVisibleViewController.view];
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `remove the current childViewController`?  In a `TabBar` set up, the separate views only have their `viewDidLoad` method called the first time they're loaded onto the screen.  If you remove the views from the navigation stack, you have to completely reload them, and this is different from how a `TabBar` works.  Is there a way to accomplish something similar to how the `TabBar` where the views aren't fully removed?

Comment: When you initialize the TabBar it keeps an array of the viewControllers. So your right, viewDidLoad is only called once. All you have to do to achieve that is keep an array of all your viewControllers and switch them from there. I can post code on this if you want, it seemed a bit overkill for the initial question.

Comment: You don't need to post code, but if you move the explanation you provided in the comment into your answer, that'd be nice.  I can figure out the code as long as I understand the concept.

Comment: Sure thing, I posted code incase anyone else needs a look at it.

Comment: @random Thanks for your answer. Can you clarify why in point 2 you use UIView's not UIViewController's?

Comment: @Joseph calling addChildViewController doesn't do anything related to UI. So each time you switched you would have to set the frame of the childViewController, remove the old childVC's view, then add the new one. Which is bad design. Using two UIView's you keep your xib clean and makes switching around the childViewController and it's UIView much easier. Not to mention playing with one UIView's autoresizingMask is much easier than trying to deal with multiple.

Comment: Ah ok. Am I right in saying that a UIViewController element is simply the class sitting behind a UIView?

Comment: @Joseph bingo. UIViewController is the "brain" if you will and UIView is the facial features. Terrible analogy but you get the point.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a container view controller as a root of your layout, and then have child view controller for left hand side menu, and another view controller for currently selected item/tab.
Then upon selection, you would simply swap the (child) view controller on the right (i.e. remove current one from parent view controller and add a new one).
Although it may sound a bit more complicated a first, it's more robust and easier to implement more complex scenarios when you move on with your project.

Comment: Ok, that sounds good. So in storyboard editor do I use containers to add the child view controllers?

Comment: Yes, you can add container view controller in IB and create embed segue to add child view controller. However you need to handle swapping child view controllers yourself, IB doesn't really support it at the moment.